# Which is correct and in what context: John was the architect of the Royal Hotel, or John is the architect of the Royal Hotel

Tags: grammar

I am curious about the use of "was" and "is" when referencing art or architecture that was designed or created in the past, but whose authorship is being disclosed in the present. Does saying "is" the architect convey a feeling of the design being in progress as compared to saying "was" which might convey that the work is done? But shouldn't the authorship still continue into the present?

Comment: Why do you think one of those is "wrong"? The native speaker can't be wrong: he's just saying two different things so it's your job to hear both of these.  Say whatever you please, just understand that when you say two different things, you  say two different things.

Comment: I'd need to do a more thorough investigation, but I'd agree that both are possible. As you intuit, if discussing a new building, it's more common to use "is" but with an older building or a dead architect "was" might be more usual. You can search for stuff like (Frank Lloyd) "Wright is/was the architect". If you're writing a passage in the past or present tense it makes sense to use a matching tense. "Wright was born... Wright studied... Wright was the architect of..."

Comment: If they've been dead more than a century it's more or less normal to use the past tense.

Comment: Like the above, there seems no definitive answer.  At the extremes, I would be inclined to reject "John is the architect..." if John is not now living or if the building is not yet complete.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s see . . .

> *Leonardo da Vinci is the artist who painted the* Mona Lisa.

Check.

Both of your propositions are fine, and when it comes to the “literary present,” doing vs. done and dead vs. alive don’t much matter:

> Literary works, paintings, films, and other artistic creations are
> assumed to exist in an eternal present. Therefore, when you write
> about writers or artists as they express themselves in their work, use
> the present tense.
>  <sub>Source: [Vanderbilt University Writing
> Studio — How (and Why) Do I Write in Literary Present
> Tense?](https://www.vanderbilt.edu/writing/resources/handouts/how-and-why-do-i-write-in-literary-present-tense/)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the building's construction is complete, that John was the architect for the entire duration of the project, and that John is not dead, you can say either "John is the architect" or "John was the architect," since both statements are true.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct, for a completed work and an architect who is still alive.

One would perhaps prefer "is" when the person is in the room now, or about to speak next, or the conversation is about this building which has recently been built. It conveys a sense of immediacy.

More commonly one would say "was". Even if one were introducing the architect, who was about to (for example) give a lecture, and we're listing his previous works, one would probably say "was" except perhaps for the very latest building that has just been built.

Answer (score 0):

We generally use "is" when describing a relationship that's still true at the current time. Since authorship doesn't change over time, it's acceptable to use "is".

If you were to add other details that are time-dependant and no longer true, you would shift to the past tense. Compare:

> Joe is the creator of ChatGPT.

with

> Joe was the OpenAI programmer who created ChatGPT.

You would use the latter if Joe is no longer at OpenAI, even though he's still the creator of ChatGPT.